# Add a CSV content to another CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two CSV files, both have same header:

```
ID,Relation,First Name,Last Name,Email Address,Office,Phone,Photos
```

I'm trying to make a PowerShell scrip to copy 2nd csv file at the end of the first, without the header.

Is there a way to eliminate duplicate records based on a certain column, after I added the two together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to group your records on a specific (or multiple) column. Then you could iterate over the list using `Foreach-Object` and just select the first entry in each group which will give you a distinct list. Finally you can export the CSV back using the `Export-Csv` cmdlet:

```
Import-Csv "your-csv.path"  | 
    Group -Property 'Id' | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.Group | select -first 1} |
    Export-Csv -Path 'your_csv.path'
```